# AppointmentItem "From" property

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

I have this code to create an Outlook appointment from an Excel sheet. It's working fine. But I am using 2 e-mail accounts on Outlook and I don't know how to alternate the meeting host between these accounts. What is the property of AppointmentItem Object, that changes the meeting host?

PS: Isn't "Organizer", I have already tried.

[image]

---

### @EDIT:

I was trying to use `.SendUsingAccount`as suggested by Macro Man, but, still not changing the sender.

My code:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ItemAppoint = oApp.CreateItem(1)
ItemAppoint.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

'===============Accounts===============
 Dim Var As Object
 Set Var = ItemAppoint.session.accounts

'======================================

With ItemAppoint
    .SendUsingAccount = Var(2) 'The account that I want to use is the index "2"
    .Subject = "Sub"
    .Body = "text"
    .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Organizer` property is read-only, you're after the `.SendUsingAccount` property which is read/write

```
AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount
```

More information on the MSDN pages: [AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868952.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, this is it. A lot of work to use this property, but it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer (the tick on the left) if it solved your problem.

Comment: crap. I not working yet. Please check this link: https://i.gyazo.com/72a3dd0d4097f23c3bb94ad64ee2ac6c.png is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

The [AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/ff868952%28v=office.14%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property allows to specify an Account object that represents the account under which the AppointmentItem is to be sent.

> What is the property of AppointmentItem Object, that changes the meeting host?

The easiest way is to create an appointment item in the calendar folder which belongs to a particular account. What code do you use for creating appointment items?

The [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article explains all possible ways for creating appointment items in Outlook. Try to get the right folder and use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx) method of the `Items` class. For example:

```
 items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
```

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Store` class returns a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the FolderType argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Answer (score 0):

This works Well.

```
Sub Test()
Dim oNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oCalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItems As Outlook.items
Dim strEntryID As String
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oNamespace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
For Each i In oNamespace.Folders
    If i.Name = "yourEmailIDhere" Then
        For Each j In i.Folders
            If j.Name = "Calendar" Then
                strEntryID = j.EntryID
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
Set oCalendarFolder = oNamespace.GetFolderFromID(strEntryID)
oItems = oCalendarFolder.items
oMeeting = oItems.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
oMeeting.Save
oMeeting.Display`
```

End sub`

Answer (score 0):

I just arrived to this question when searching for a solution to the same problem: in my case the appointment was being created for a different account than desired, and the `.SendUsingAccount` property was of no help.

I managed to solve this by directly creating the appointment inside the folder I wanted:

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set AppointItem = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("secondary@hostname.com").Folders("Calendar").Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
```

Now the appointment is created for the `secondary@hostname.com` account, and not for the `default@hostname.com` account.